# Join table data gets deleted when updating an entity in ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have this Recipe entity with ManyToMany relationship with Category entity

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "recipe_category", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
 "recipe_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
private Set<Category> categories;
```

The relationship in the Category entity is this.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
 private Set<Recipe> recipes;
```

The Recipe, Category, Recipe_Category gets created along with a bunch of other tables based on other entities. However, when I edit Recipe, the data in the join table Recipe_Category gets deleted.

Why is this behavior and what I need to do to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only remove join table data(Recipe_Category)? I think to need confirmation your JPA settings to EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Yeah only the join table data. I'm using Spring Data Repository. Both CategoryRepository and RecipeRepository interfaces extends CrudRepository. So, no explicit use of EntityManager.